# $f''(x)>0$ except finite many points

Tags: analysis

let $f(x)$ be a function defined on $I$. Its derivative function $f'(x)$ exists on $I$. Except a finite number of points, $f''(x)>0$. Is $f(x)$ convex?

First, if there is a point $x_0$ such that $f''(x_0)<0$, by Darboux's theorem, $f'(x)$ should take all values between $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_1)$, here $f(x_1)>0$. So there must be infinite points taking negative values since there are infinite negative numbers betwenn these two numbers. Contradiction.

Now we have $f''(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ having second derivative. And if $f(x)$ has second derivative on $I$, $f(x)$ must be convex. However, what if there are some points where $f''(x)$ does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that $f'$ is monotone increasing. Let $x_1 < x_2 < ...< x_k$ be a points in which $f''(x)\leq 0.$ In the intervals $(x_{i-1} ,x_i ) $ and $(x_i , x_{i+1} )$ the derivative $f'$ is monotone increasing. So it is enough to show that $f'(y) \leq f'(x_i ) \leq f'(x) $ for all $x\in (x_i , x_{i+1} ) , y\in (x_{i-1} , x_i ).$ Suppose for example that $ f(x_i) >f(t) $ for some $t\in (x_i , x_{i+1})$ since $f'$ has a Darboux property then there exists $s\in (x_i , t)$ such that $$f'(s) =\frac{f'(x_i) +f'(t)}{2} >f'(t)$$ but this is impossible since $f'$ is monotone increasing on the interval $(x_i , x_{i+1 } ).$

This shows that $$f'(x_i) \leq f'(x) $$ for all $x\in (x_i , x_{i+1} ).$

Analogously we can prove that:$$f'(x_i) \geq f'(y) $$ for all $y\in (x_{i-1} , x_{i} ).$

So in this way we prove that $f'$ is monotone increasing on $I$ and therefore $f$ is convex function on $I.$